# read russian characters with silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I parse XML file. And I need to read russian letters.

But none of supported encodings(BigEndian,UTF8,Unicode) can do it.

```
FileStream f = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
StreamReader s = new StreamReader(f, Encoding.?);
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an encoding that matches the file you are trying to parse.  If the encoding is not one of the ones natively supported by Silverlight, you will have to supply your own sub-class of System.Text.Encoding to handle the file; it must convert the bytes in the file into the correct Unicode characters.  If you identify the standard name for your encoding, you might do a search and find an implementation already exists; otherwise, you must write your own.